# The best way to collision check in WP

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, query

E.g. I have a random number generated by a PHP code

`$random`

And I need to make a check if this number doesn't exist in any of my posts in DB in my meta field called

`unique_code`

What is the preffered way in WP to check if this value(random number) exist or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in mechanism for searching the meta table for a `key`/`value` pair other than a full blown post search with `WP_Query`. I'd consider that overkill. Just query the table:

```
$unique = $wpdb->get_var(
  "SELECT meta_id 
  FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
  WHERE meta_key = 'unique_code' 
  AND meta_value = '{$random}' 
  LIMIT 1"
);
```

I can't help but think that more detail in the question might point to a better way to proceed